# HTML file loads smaller elements in ElectronJS, how do I fix that?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron, desktop-application

I am currently creating my first ElectronJS App. When I tried loading my html (+css) file it seems as if everything is displayed smaller.

```
function createWindow() {
const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1000,
    height: 600,
    useContentSize: true,
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true
    }
});

win.loadFile('index.html');
```

As you can see the window is **1000x600 pixels**. This is how the ElectronJS app looks when I run it (**the width of the sidebar is set to 1000px**)
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzNmV.png)

A sidebar with a width of 1000px should cover the whole page since the window is 1000px wide as well, right?

Comment: The best you can do is to open DevTools and check what is going on there. Use `BrowserWindow.webContents.openDevTools()` in your code.

Comment: Please post the content of `index.html`, maybe the problem is in your CSS

Comment: Also, this could be a zoom state, have you tried pressing `Ctrl+0`?

Comment: @snwflk you were right, this worked for me. Simpler than I thought!